# Receive a file using runscript (minicom scripting language)?

Tags: script, file-transfer, serial-port

With runscript one can script minicom serial line sessions. I try to script the reception of a file transferred with ymodem. Minicom uses external programs for file transmission. I tried runscript's "!"-command which opens a shell, but I am not able to connect to the data stream within this shell. Do you know how to receive a file with rb or sexyz from within a minicom runscript script?

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution. I used an expect script instead, which gets started from within a shell script. The expect script spawns picocom to connect and then navigates through the menus of the remote device and starts the file transfer. The shell script takes over again and starts sexyz:
`code`
exec 5<"$PORT"; 
exec 6>"$PORT"; 
sexyz -k ry "$DATA_DIR/" <&5 >&6`code`
It nevertheless would be intresting to know how to do it with runscript...

Comment: Will be nice if you could share the expect script...

Comment: The expect script is very specific to the device I'm steering, it navigates through the text menus and starts the file transfer of the device.